# Keep button on the same position while scrolling

Tags: tailwind-css

With Tailwind CSS, how could I make a button that stays at the bottom of the page while scrolling?

Something similar to the "Sign up for free" button at [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/).

Comment: Please share some reproducible code

Comment: As per my knowledge , this can't be solely achieved by tailwind-css, it needs a little of js to listen to scroll and then show the div , these link might help you https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c & https://plainenglish.io/blog/hiding-dom-elements-in-react-based-on-scrolling-d9a9ef1f1f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tailwind CSS you can use `position` of `fixed`. To make it show on response to the scroll, you'll be needing JavaScript or [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

```html
<div class="">

  <!-- Hello divs to make the div scroll -->

  <div class="fixed bg-blue-600 bottom-0 rounded-full text-white text-2xl right-0 p-4 m-20">Sign Up For Free</div>
</div>
```

[image]

##### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y8pyDISHAi)